# Error : SharePoint Designer does not support editing non-SharePoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

When i open my SharePoint Designer i get the following error:

[image]

What should i do to resolve it.

Comment: This fix above did not work as the site is not sharepoint site. This site was created outside of sharepoint. i could at one time edit non sharepoint files with Designer so what changed.

Answer (score 5):

To solve the issue, you can try the steps below and share with us the outcomes:

1. Restart your SharePoint Designer 2013 and re-try to open the site.
2. Clear the SharePoint Designer cache via the steps in the thread:
   [How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/)
3. Reinstall the application via this location : 
   [SharePoint Designer 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491)

Answer (score 1):

The location where we enter the URL did make a difference for me. Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Typing the URL in the address bar at the top is the same as not entering anything in the Site name field. This is essentially a 'typo' answer and does not address how to resolve the error shown above.

Answer (score -1):

Try using different connection could also solve the issue. I have experienced a similar problem with slow speed connection (a 4G modem), when using a faster connection I could connect it (another 4G network but has good coverage).

Comment: This does not address the issue at all. Network connection speed is among the least relevant (if it is relevant _at all_) things with regard to resolving this error.